# Ranking theory for rainfall station

Tags: r, missing-data, ranking, ranks, database

I have 10 rainfall stations. Each station has a rain day, no-rain day, and NA value, all in percentages.

How can I rank these stations based on the condition that the best station is station that has high rain days, low no-rain days, and low NA values?

```
dput(head(rain))
structure(c(4800, 1298, 1528, 2066, 3401, 3197, 43.81, 11.85, 
13.95, 18.86, 31.04, 29.18, 3880, 6591, 5964, 5290, 4642, 5489, 
35.41, 60.15, 54.43, 48.28, 42.37, 50.1, 2277, 3068, 3465, 3601, 
2914, 2271, 20.78, 28, 31.62, 32.86, 26.59, 20.73), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("Tapanuli", "Riau", "Jambi", "Tanjungpinang", 
"Kepri", "Lampung"), c("NA (days)", "%", "No Rain (Days)", "%", 
"Rain (Days)", "%")), class = "table")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (albeit r-free) solution may be to just paste your data frame in Excel or similar and create a table, then choose the drop-down options for the columns to order largest to smallest in "Rain (Days)" column, then smallest to largest in "No Rain (Days)", then smallest to largest for "NA (Days)". You can then create a column "Ranking" number them 1-6.

A solution in R using the `frank` function from `data.frame`. I renamed your percentage column names so they are unique to r - rain days, nr - no rain days, na - NA days. The '-' denotes descending order.

```
rain$rank <- data.table::frank(rain, r, -nr, -na, ties.method = "min")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, appreciate that!

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

In your example all variables are dependent. The higher "rain" the lower both other variables. This makes the problem a bit more trickier.

How ever a first draft can be to draw a ternary plot of the percentages. With this, you might be able to identify the criteria to rank in more detail.

As a starting point, my suggestion is based on a few assumptions as following. How ever this does not reflect the dependence between variables:

- you do not put different importance onto the different variables
- absolute number of days is not important, e.g. only the variance within one variable is of interest for ranking
- I assume an underlying normal distribution

Therefore I recommend to standardize the variables each. Now, they have each distribution has the same width and is placed around zero. Now easily add up the different variables, but be aware that some signs has to be adjusted to reflect the "the lower the better" and "the higher the better" statement.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will try to do that.